# Java List<String> to Map<String, Integer> convertion

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to convert a `Map <String, Integer>` from `List<String>` in java 8 something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> namesMap = names.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> name, 0));
```

because I have a list of Strings, and I'd like to to create a Map, where the key is the string of the list, and the value is Integer (a zero).

My goal is, to counting the elements of String list (later in my code).

I know it is easy to convert it, in the "old" way;

```
Map<String,Integer> namesMap = new HasMap<>();
for(String str: names) {
  map1.put(str, 0);
}
```

but I'm wondering there is a Java 8 solution as well.

Comment: Just change `0` to `name -> 0`: `Map<String, Integer> namesMap = names.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> name, name -> 0));` but this will fail if you have duplicates. If you want to count occurrences, do it right in the first place: `Map<String, Long> namesMap = names.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(name -> name, Collectors.counting()));` Instead of `name -> name`, you can also use `Function.identity()`.

Comment: Ohh it is working, thank you! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As already noted, the parameters to [`Collectors.toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) have to be functions, so you have to change `0` to `name -> 0` (you can use any other parameter name instead of `name`).

Note, however, that this will fail if there are duplicates in `names`, as that will result in duplicate keys in the resulting map. To fix this, you could pipe the stream through [`Stream.distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) first:

```
Map<String, Integer> namesMap = names.stream().distinct()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 0));
```

Or don't initialize those defaults at all, and use [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) or [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead:

```
int x = namesMap.getOrDefault(someName, 0);
int y = namesMap.computeIfAbsent(someName, s -> 0);
```

Or, if you want to get the counts of the names, you can just use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.counting`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--):

```
Map<String, Long> counts = names.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 9):

the `toMap` collector receives two mappers - one for the key and one for the value. The key mapper could just return the value from the list (i.e., either `name -> name` like you currently have, or just use the builtin `Function.Identity`). The value mapper should just return the hard-coded value of `0` for any key:

```
namesMap = 
    names.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), name -> 0));
```